Assign a value by ref to a class member by ref
Something is confusing me, and I hope you can maybe clarify.
// This class assumes that T is definitively compatible to TheStruct
class ValueHolder<T> {
  T _value;
  TheStruct _structValue;

  void Test1() {
    _structValue = ref Unsafe<T, TheStruct>(ref _value); // ERROR: _structValue is not a by-ref value
    // _structValue = Unsafe<T, TheStruct>(ref _value); // WORKS: Copy from stack to heap
  }

  void Test2() {
    ref var structValue = ref _structValue;
    structValue = ref Unsafe.As<T, TheStruct>(ref _value); // WORKS: Why, and what implication does it have?
  }
}

So my question is in Test2: Why I can assign Unsafe.As as ref, when defining ref var structValue = ref _structValue;. And more important, what does it have for implications, when using this over _structValue = Unsafe<T, TheStruct>(ref _value);?
Thanks for reading and I hope you can bring some light into this. :)

ref var structValue = ref _structValue;
structValue = ref Unsafe.As<T, TheStruct>(ref _value); // WORKS: Why, and what implication does it have?


Why I can assign Unsafe.As as ref, when defining ref var structValue =
ref _structValue;

Because you can reassign the reference of a ref local to another reference.
This example will make things clear I hope:
var foo = 42;
var bar = 1;

ref var refVar = ref foo;
refVar++; // as if we wrote foo++
Console.WriteLine(foo); // 43

refVar = ref bar; // at this point we detach refVar as alias for foo

refVar++; // as if we wrote bar++
Console.WriteLine(foo); // still 43
Console.WriteLine(bar); // 2

So to your original question:
ref var structValue = ref _structValue;
structValue = ref Unsafe.As<T, TheStruct>(ref _value); // WORKS: Why, and what implication does it have?

the second line won't assign to the field _structvalue the reference that Unsafe.As returns. It will assign the reference to the local variable structValue.
So when Test2 returns, you have actually done nothing to the field _structValue. In Test1 for the working part you actually did copy the value which was there at the moment from _value:
_structValue = Unsafe<T, TheStruct>(ref _value);

Future changes to _value won't be reflected in _structValue.
You may want to look in to ref structs available from .NET 7, where you can have not only ref local variables, but ref fields such as:
ref TheStruct _structValue;

If you did what you wanted, however,
_structValue = ref Unsafe.As<T, TheStruct>(ref _value); 

the compiler will issue this error:
CS8374 Cannot ref-assign 'Unsafe.As<T, TheStruct>(ref _value)' to '_structValue' because 'Unsafe.As<T, TheStruct>(ref _value)' has a narrower escape scope than '_structValue'.

which I think is a bit strange, because it is a field in the same struct...but that's maybe another question.

I am fully aware of it, that the left-hand side must be a ref variable, if you want to assign a ref variable, but the question is, why I can do this: structValue = ref Unsafe.As<T, TheStruct>(ref _value); where structValue is defined as ref var structValue = ref _structValue;. Does Unsafe.As<,> not internally remap its memory and would lead such an ref assignment not violate the valid scope of the return ref value of Unsafe.As<,>??

Another view: when Unsafe.As<,> ref assigns to ref var structValue = ref _structValue;, would it not corrupt the memory at the address _structValue when Test2 returned? So what do I actually assign ultimatively to _structvalue? The same address of _value I passed to Unsafe.As<T, TheStruct>(ref _value)?

@Teneko I've edited my answer. you don't assign anything to _structValue in the second example. You assign to the local ref variable structValue.

Thanks, I understood now. The last compiler error you mentioned was the error I actually expected in my second example. Your example was indeed very insightful. I now understand, that I just replace the ref address of the local ref and not the address of the referenced value of that local ref.

I also find it somewhat strange, but I think the Unsafe.As<,> overload does not know whether the by-ref value is scoped to local or to field, thus it scopes its ref returned value always to local.
